# How to query the total byte length of a record in a mysql table(s)?

Tags: mysql, information-schema

SHOW TABLE STATUS just gives me the average row length which is not the same.

I could just go through the column definitions and add them up. But that's a lot of work if I have a lot of tables. I can calculate it with a query off of the information_schema but I feel like there has to be an easier way?

It would be ideal if it could give me the total with and without the BLOB/TEXT fields.

This seems fairly fundamental and so I'm guessing there's a built in solution.

Anyone know?

Answer (score 0):

This is what I've come up with so far.

```
SELECT
    TABLE_SCHEMA,
    TABLE_NAME,
    SUM(CHARACTER_OCTET_LENGTH) AS total_table_octets,
    SUM(CHARACTER_MAXIMUM_LENGTH) AS total_table_chars,
    SUM(IF(DATA_TYPE IN('blob', 'text', 'mediumtext', 'longtext', 'mediumblob', 'longblob'), CHARACTER_OCTET_LENGTH, 0)) AS blob_octets,
    SUM(IF(DATA_TYPE IN('blob', 'text', 'mediumtext', 'longtext', 'mediumblob', 'longblob'), 0, CHARACTER_OCTET_LENGTH)) AS octets_without_blobs_text
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
-- WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA IN ('test')
GROUP BY TABLE_SCHEMA, TABLE_NAME
ORDER BY total_table_octets desc
LIMIT 30;
```